# Some assets not loading in an old Rails 3-2-stable app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, digital-ocean

**BIG UPDATES AT THE BOTTOM OF THIS POST**

I have a Rails 3-2-stable app that I'm moving to a new server so I can work on upgrading it to Rails 5.  Currently, it's hosted on Heroku and most of the assets show up just fine (the app Just Works (TM)).  I have a few random assets that will not show up after precompilation on a Digital Ocean droplet.  I'm deploying with Capistrano.

The error for the assets that won't show up look something like this:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://stage.fancy-new-droplet.com/assets/application/application.js”.
```

In some cases, there will be a hash associated with the asset like this:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://stage.fancy-new-droplet.com/assets/application/certifications-56046476595984b00d1267a4f02822e5.js
```

In the former case, the asset is actually in `public/assets/` as opposed to `public/assets/application/` on the droplet.  Moving or symlinking the missing asset to that location doesn't seem to affect anything.  In the latter case, the assets just don't exist anywhere on the droplet as far as I can tell.

For the case with no hashes in filenames, changing my include tags from this:

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application/application" %>`

To something like this:

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Will solve the issue but I feel like that's a red herring given the other assets that don't seem to exist after precompilation.

I did run into an esoteric issue where the droplet was running out of memory and silently failing halfway through asset compilation but I increased the available memory and it doesn't even use half the memory now.  It does max out the CPU 100%, though.  I may try to increase both CPU and memory on the droplet.

Here are the relevant asset compilation lines from `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

And the relevant asset compilation lines from `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Locally, everything works 100% just peachy, no errors.  Assets load fine and we're all good.  Here's the asset pipeline bits from my `development.rb` file:

```
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
```

I've run various combinations of `rake assets:clean`, `rake assets:precompile`, and `rake assets:precompile:all` on the production server (in the production environment) and I've even nuked the public/assets/ folder to start it all over again.  All to no avail.

What might cause these assets to not be created on our droplet while they do manage to get created on Heroku?

**EDIT**

As requested, my DO stack is simply just a droplet (2vcpu, 2gb ram), I'm using Puma and Nginx.  Here is my Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'

install_plugin Capistrano::Puma

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**FURTHER EDIT**

I've frobbed `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` a couple of times in `application.rb` and ran various permutations of `rake assets:clean, assets:precompile`, and `assets:precompile:all` with `RAILS_ENV=production` locally to no avail.

**YET ANOTHER EDIT**

I've noticed at this point that precompiling production assets seems to not be compiling four of the javascript files, and about seven of the css files.  It also doesn't seem to put application.js into `public/assets/application/application.js` (where the app is looking), rather it lands in `public/assets/application.js`.

**MORE EDITS**

I have resolved the issue of the JavaScript assets not loading by fixing a `require_tree` statement in `application.js` and now the only issue seems to be several missing CSS files.

In this application there are two directories with css files:

- `app/assets/stylesheets/`
- `app/assets/stylesheets/application`

There are a total of 21 stylesheets that do not load out of nearly 100 total.  The stylesheets that don't load are being called with a hashed filename (`somefile-hash.css`) but those hashed files don't exist in `public/assets/` on the droplet.

Here's the requires from `application.css.scss`:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require chosen
 *= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 *= require feature-carousel
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Out of frustration, I added `= require_directory ./assets` to that list and now I've only got about 15 stylesheets failing to compile/load.  That behaviour doesn't make any sense to me as I assumed the `= require_tree .` would've covered the wonky subdirectory.

Individually specifying files `= require foo` or `= require foo.css.scss` does not seem to affect anything, either.

I also bumped the `config.assets.version` out of frustration to no avail.

And furthermore, no amount of foul language can persuade these assets to compile.

Comment: * Look at the logs under the `Activity` tab on Heroku to get an idea of what commands are being run on heroku.

* Are you sure you are running your code in production mode on the droplet? How did you verify this? Doing varies from setup to setup.

* When you run rake assets:precompile do you see the compiled files, with fingerprints, in the public/assets directory?

* Was the heroku system setup to use a CDN?

Comment: Also be aware that older versions of rails would generate both a fingerprinted and a non-fingerprinted version of the asset. Sometimes people would create links to the non-fingerprinted version by mistake. New versions of rails should only generate the fingerprinted versions, so view your html and be sure all asset links are fingerprinted.

Comment: I'm running in production mode.  `RAILS_ENV` is set to production and logging goes to `log/production.rb`.  I'm running the same commands on Heroku at the moment.  I do not see all of the compiled files in `public/assets` when i run `rake assets:precompile`, I only see some of them, which is the issue with my question.  Heroku was not set up to run a CDN.  Of the missing assets, I have neither fingerprinted nor nonfingerprinted copies of them apparently post-compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asset pipeline concatenates your assets to only generate and serve specified files, 'application.js', 'application.css' and images/fonts by default.

If you are explicitly including other css/js files in your application via the `javascript_include_tag` or `stylesheet_link_tag` helpers, you'll need to add those files manually to the pipeline via the `config.assets.precompile +=` setting in your `application.rb` or an initializer.

Currently, those files should already be included within your `application` manifest via the `require_tree .` directive. So, the styles might be being applied right now too. If that's the case, you can just remove your code that adds the individual stylesheets separately to get rid of the 404s.

Still not sure how the app is working fine on heroku, maybe you have some heroku config that's enabling serving the static assets.

Comment: This was it!  Thanks so much!  I have to add each file individually but it works.  I can't give it `*.css` due to a bug in an ancient version of a bootstrap gem included with the project but I'll take it.  Thanks again!  I'll award the bounty as soon as stack overflow unlocks it.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try changing these in production.rb but no guarantees, may be worth trying.

```
config.serve_static_files = true
config.assets.compile = false
```

Also if you have this in Gemfile, you might wanna try to comment it out and bundle install locally before deploy.

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

That was required by Heroku but you may not need it on DO.  See https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor

Also, please if you can post more relevant info about your DO stack and maybe your Capfile

Comment: I don't have `rails_12factor` in my Gemfile anywhere.  Making the suggested changes to my production.rb file throws a 500 `ActionView::Template::Errror` for the first CSS asset, stating that it's not precompiled.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing this on your `production.rb` should work:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: this did not change any behaviour on my end.